# How to convert the QSQLDatabase into QDataStream to save it. its sqite database

Tags: c++, database, qt, c++11, qtsql

I need for project to convert a QSqlDatabase obejct which is db that I work on project to the QDataStream so I could save it as a db dump file which I can later import again to the project to work on as there are parts where we need to remove the db and its contents.

Was reading documentation but can't find proper way to do this. 
I need it for sort of export and save as dialog and also for import dialog.
Dialogs
 are implemented but I'm not sure how to do this.

```
QDataStream out(&file);
out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_DefaultCompiledVersion);
QSqlDatabase db = storage->database();
out << db;
```

Storage::database() function return current db in the QSqlDatabase format and I need it converted.

Comment: QSqlDatabase is a class that manages the connection, it does not store information except credentials.

Comment: Thank you for fast answer so then what would be proper way to export the database. beside doing the dirty way of QFile:copy().

Comment: think that this is the easiest option, why do not you want to use it?

Comment: Because then can't really ask user for the filename but will probably use it for now.

Comment: What do you mean, you can not ask for the filename?

Comment: You can know the file name from db instance! you said sqlite3.

Comment: Well yes but that is not important as I can make use of other way to sequence db backup files.

Comment: Yes I do know the name that is currently used I wanted to leave option to user to choose a name to save file. Anyway thx for a heads up I will do it as copy for now.

Comment: I guess I will later run the sql query to dump the data as for now the sqlite is not encrypted but will be in future so then backing up encrypted blob if you delete a key is useless so will have a unencrypted backup version for that.